# Metaplex - Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: solana-program, metaplex, metadata

I'm really strugling to much on this one as I don't understand my error.
My goal is to imput metadata on my token thx to Metaplex and here is my code :

```
   import {Collection, CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts, 
   CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs, Creator, MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID, 
    UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts, UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData, 
    Uses, createMetadataAccountV3, updateMetadataAccountV2, findMetadataPda} from 
   "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata"; import * as web3 from 
   "@solana/web3.js"; import { PublicKey, createSignerFromKeypair,
   isKeypairSigner, none, signerIdentity, some } from
   "@metaplex-foundation/umi"; import { createUmi } from
   '@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults'; import {
   fromWeb3JsKeypair, fromWeb3JsPublicKey} from
   '@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters';

   export function loadWalletKey(keypairFile:string): web3.Keypair {
   const fs = require("fs");
   const loaded = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(
     new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairFile).toString())),
   );
   return loaded;   }

   const INITIALIZE = true;

   async function main(){
   const myKeypair = loadWalletKey("Nico9i5BasPEndBCFNiQ1RBQckzsDH1KWW6zXaXehZG.json")
   const mint = new web3.PublicKey("EgrbFEpsLX6eBZ25i11QPBQW3Dvum8yVEQetT5DwpHHx");

   const umi = createUmi("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
   const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, fromWeb3JsKeypair(myKeypair))
   umi.use(signerIdentity(signer, true))

   const ourMetadata = { // TODO change those values!
       name: "SkullKingTrash", 
       symbol: "SSKT",
       uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TrashColaFR/uri/main/test.json",
   }
   const onChainData = {
       ...ourMetadata,
       // we don't need that
       sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
       creators: none<Creator[]>(),
       collection: none<Collection>(),
       uses: none<Uses>(),
   }
   if(INITIALIZE){
       const accounts: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts = {
           mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint),
           mintAuthority: signer,
       }
       const data: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs = {
           isMutable: true,
           collectionDetails: null,
           data: onChainData
       }
       const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {...accounts, ...data}).sendAndConfirm(umi);
       console.log(txid)
   } else {
       const data: UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData = {
           data: some(onChainData),
           discriminator: 0,
           isMutable: some(true),
           newUpdateAuthority: none<PublicKey>(),
           primarySaleHappened: none<boolean>()
       }
       const accounts: UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts = {
           metadata: findMetadataPda(umi,{mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint)}),
           updateAuthority: signer
       }
       const txid = await updateMetadataAccountV2(umi, {...accounts, ...data} ).sendAndConfirm(umi);
       console.log(txid)
   }

   }

    main(); `
```

While the error is :

> SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction
> simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of
> a prior credit.
> at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\nicol\Documents\TokenSol2\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5921:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\nicol\Documents\TokenSol2\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:5880:20)
> at async Object.sendTransaction (C:\Users\nicol\Documents\TokenSol2\node_modules@metaplex-foundation\umi-rpc-web3js\src\createWeb3JsRpc.ts:327:25)
>
> at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (C:\Users\nicol\Documents\TokenSol2\node_modules@metaplex-foundation\umi\src\TransactionBuilder.ts:359:23)
> at async main (C:\Users\nicol\Documents\TokenSol2\mpl_metadata.ts:49:22) {   logs:
> [] }

I’m a beginner, but I guess it’s not that hard. Someone more educated might be able to help me with this one

Answer (score 1):

The wallet `myKeypair` is set as the signer for the umi instance. This means that it'll act as the payer and transaction fees will be debited from it.

The error likely means that this wallet hasn't been funded, and so has 0 SOL in it to pay for fees. There are a few ways to get devnet SOL, once of which is to run:

```
solana airdrop <amount> <your-wallet-address> --url d
```

To request a devnet airdrop to the specified wallet using the solana-cli. Note that this has rate-limits of about 2 SOL per hour, but that should be enough for what you need.

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for your quick answer ! 

The problem is, I'm in the mainnet, and my sol account is of 0.24 already : 

'> solana airdrop 0.001 Nico9i5BasPEndBCFNiQ1RBQckzsDH1KWW6zXaXehZG --url d 
Requesting airdrop of 0.001 SOL
Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.
> solana balance Nico9i5BasPEndBCFNiQ1RBQckzsDH1KWW6zXaXehZG                  
0.24647912 SOL
>'

Comment: Your script tries to run on devnet: `const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com");`, and thus fails due to a lack of devnet sol. If you have mainnet sol then changing the rpc url to a mainnet url in the script should fix the error, as then your wallet would have an adequate balance

You can only

Comment: I saw it thanks to your first message and sadly changing for : 
const umi = createUmi(new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"));

Or this 
const umi = createUmi("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
didn't help

Comment: But once again, huge thanks for your help

Comment: I've made an update of my @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata and it runs without any issue ! 
FINALLY ! 